# Sending a JSON file using ActiveMQ

Tags: java, json, activemq-classic

I'm writing a JAVA application that sends a JSON file using ActiveMQ. I downloaded the libraries from this open source: http://activemq.apache.org/download.html.

What should happen is that the place where I am sending the JSON file to should use it and a response should be displayed on the screen. I have another application that works, but I want to have another one that prints out to the command line. However, with what I have written, that does not happen. It appears that my code does connect to some URL, but I'm not sure if I am doing  it correctly since this is my first time using it. Can someone confirm if I am doing this correctly or if I am missing something?

```
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;

import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.DeliveryMode;
import javax.jms.Destination;
import javax.jms.ExceptionListener;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageConsumer;
//import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
//import java.util.Iterator;

//import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

public class SimRunner {

static String topic = null;
static String url = null;
static String msg = null;
static String jsonFile = null;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

    url = "tcp://localhost:45125";
    jsonFile = "c:\\example\\file.json";
    System.out.println("ActiveMQ url: " + url);
    System.out.println("JSON File: " + jsonFile);

    //read JSON file and parse/set topic
    try {
        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(jsonFile));

        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
        msg = jsonObject.toJSONString().replace("\\/", "/");

        topic = ((String) jsonObject.get("topic"));
        System.out.println("Message queue/topic: " + topic);
        System.out.println("Message (from file): " + msg);

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
}

    thread(new Producer(), false);
    thread(new Consumer(), false);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}

public static void thread(Runnable runnable, boolean daemon) {
    Thread brokerThread = new Thread(runnable);
    brokerThread.setDaemon(daemon);
    brokerThread.start();
}

  public static class Producer implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        try {
            // Create a ConnectionFactory
            ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(url);

            // Create a Connection
            Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
            connection.start();

            // Create a Session
            Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

            // Create the destination (Topic or Queue)
            Destination destination = session.createQueue(topic);

            // Create a MessageProducer from the Session to the Topic or Queue
            MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
            producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);

            // Create a message
            TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage(msg);

            // Tell the producer to send the message
            producer.send(message);
            System.out.println("Sent: "+ message.getText());

            // Clean up
            session.close();
            connection.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error occured in Producer. " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public static class Consumer implements Runnable, ExceptionListener {
    public void run() {
        try {

            // Create a ConnectionFactory
            ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(url);

            // Create a Connection
            Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
            connection.start();

            connection.setExceptionListener(this);

            // Create a Session
            Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

            // Create the destination (Topic or Queue)
            Destination destination = session.createQueue(topic);

            // Create a MessageConsumer from the Session to the Topic or Queue
            MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(destination);

            // Wait for a message
            Message message = consumer.receive(1000);

            if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
                TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
                String text = textMessage.getText();
                System.out.println("Received: " + text);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Received: " + message);
            }

            consumer.close();
            session.close();
            connection.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Caught: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public synchronized void onException(JMSException ex) {
        System.out.println("JMS Exception occured.  Shutting down client.");
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you are doing but it sounds like you are trying to receive the same message with two clients using a single Queue which will not work.  Queues only dispatch a message to one client, so if you have two queue consumers subscribed they will share the message load instead of each processing the same set of messages.  If you want to have a listener that can see every single message that is sent to a queue but not disrupt normal queue operations then try using [mirrored queues](http://activemq.apache.org/mirrored-queues.html) in ActiveMQ.